# python - web scraping an ajax website using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, ajax, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape e-commerce site that uses ajax call to load its next pages.

I am able to scrape data present on page 1 but page 2 loads automatically through ajax call when I scroll page 1 to bottom.

My code :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen as ureq
my_url='http://www.shopclues.com/mobiles-smartphones.html'
page=ureq(my_url).read()
page_soup=soup(page,"html.parser")
containers=page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"column col3"})
for container in containers:
   name=container.h3.text
   price=container.find("span",{'class':'p_price'}).text
   print("Name : "+name.replace(","," "))
   print("Price : "+price)
for i in range(2,7):
    my_url="http://www.shopclues.com/ajaxCall/moreProducts?catId=1431&filters=&pageType=c&brandName=&start="+str(36*(i-1))+"&columns=4&fl_cal=1&page="+str(i)
    page=ureq(my_url).read()
    print(page)
    page_soup=soup(page,"html.parser")
    containers=page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"column col3"})
    for container in containers:
        name=container.h3.text
        price=container.find("span",{'class':'p_price'}).text
        print("Name : "+name.replace(","," "))
        print("Price : "+price)
```

I have printed the ajax page read by ureq to know whether I am able to open the ajax page and I got an output as:
[image]

b' ' are the outputs of:
    print(page)

please provide me a solution to scrape the remaining data.

Comment: try with `selenium`.

Comment: I am new to web scrapping it would be kind of you if you could provide me a code for that

Comment: I'd suggest using their APi, http://developer.shopclues.com/index.php/API_Basics#link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib2 import urlopen as ureq
import random
import time

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)

# A randomizer for the delay
seconds = 5 + (random.random() * 5)
# create a new Chrome session
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
# driver.maximize_window()

# navigate to the application home page
driver.get("http://www.shopclues.com/mobiles-smartphones.html")
time.sleep(seconds)
time.sleep(seconds)
# Add more to range for more phones
for i in range(1):
    element = driver.find_element_by_id("moreProduct")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
    time.sleep(seconds)
    time.sleep(seconds)
html = driver.page_source
page_soup = soup(html, "html.parser")
containers = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class": "column col3"})
for container in containers:
# Add error handling
    try:
        name = container.h3.text
        price = container.find("span", {'class': 'p_price'}).text
        print("Name : " + name.replace(",", " "))
        print("Price : " + price)
    except AttributeError:
        continue
driver.quit()
```

I used selenium to load the website and click the button to load more results. Then take the resulting html and put in your code.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide an explanation or documentation in your answers to further help the original poster and anybody that may search for this answer.

Comment: Sorry to say but honestly I didn't get what you are actually doing here. And moreover, I don't find any button to load more products as the page did get load itself when i scroll down to bottom.

Comment: I tried it for one more time and i got the load more button but when i clicked it the browser took me to the url : http://b.codeonclick.com/script/wait.php?stamat=m%7C%2C%2Cg3F-9jZXoGU3B_9GH0dEdHP3xP.f10%2CqqtKzScrXaD6J-TdEPg201mBMiNRUBdz6CXReBfSkvUVRInI1LXqZThgGFzCEHMpF1lleptOU_QsrpOi6T7Hby7nsDmByZIpPmfQ9jTUqKnDJMkuuIUs2gNUMD-4q8sddxXk9SJ9DV0v5jXqlTWUZdtJQpypd5folRnCfkojHyAp_deich7xrxO_f1wrkstlYSw7fGuN7n6aoTbh6DiYEF0Ypi2LPx8j3rcuOvcI8SqWq0Nn017hDlPJJxhoMjvHa67t4aRUI7sl9iV308NqAjdhpD5WQ7sYXYpfMxy-KpDzCUiL5Ndf-N_giWqeVZ-5&ttc=t4xr44rc

Comment: I apologize, while running your code i forget to see python shell and when I saw it I was shocked as your code scraped all the products. Please describe your code in detail.

Comment: I open the website with selenium, Selenium loads the webpage and click the more product after if sleep for a random time. I put it in a range so you can have it as many or as little phone to scraped. Once the range is done. It get the html from the page and run it through the BeautifulSoup code to get the products name and price. I also add error handling where it try to get a name from the text and if find none it kill the the code.

Comment: thank you @bentaylor for the detailed description. Can you please check my other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44169120/reading-ajax-website-from-urllib-request