# Beautiful Soup can't find this html

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Python3 - Beautiful Soup 4

I'm trying to parse the weather graph out of the website:
https://www.wunderground.com/forecast/us/ny/new-york-city

But when I grab the weather graph html but beautiful soup seems to grab all around it.

I am new to Beautiful Soup. I think it is not able to grab this because either  it is not able to parse the  tag thing they have going on or because the javascript that populates the graph hasn't loaded or is not parsable by BS (at least the way I'm using it).

As far as my code goes, it's extremely basic

```
import requests, bs4
url = 'https://www.wunderground.com/forecast/us/ny/new-york-city'
requrl = requests.get(url, headers={'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
requrl.raise_for_status()
bs = bs4.BeautifulSoup(requrl.text, features="html.parser")
a = str(bs)
x = 'weather-graph'
print(a[a.find('x'):])
#Also tried a.find('weather-graph') which returns -1
```

I have verified that each piece of the code works in other scenarios. The last line should find that string and print out everything after that.

I tried making x many different pieces of the html in and around the graph but got nothing of substance.

Comment: If the content is dynamically generated via on-page javascript, then requests/bs4 won't see it.  You'll have to use something like selenium.

Comment: @JohnGordon is right. As www.wunderground.com uses Angular.js, you will need to use Selenium to collect the data from the site

Comment: Duplicate of [Web scraping an ajax website using BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44165387/python-web-scraping-an-ajax-website-using-beautifulsoup)?

Comment: I'd strongly suggest not scrape wunderground. It used to be great when they offered API, but no longer do. I'd like to suggest you check out [Dark Sky API](https://darksky.net/dev). You get something like 1000 free requests/calls per day, and anything above that is $0.0001 per request (so dirt cheap).

Comment: These replies are excellent. Thank you all! 
@JohnGordon, I have used selenium, but only for automating actions, not web scraping. Good idea.

Comment: @chitown88 that is cheap! Thank you! I will check that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an API you can use. Same as the page does. Don't know if key expires. You may need to do some ordering on output but you can do that by datetime field

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://api.weather.com/v1/geocode/40.765/-73.981/forecast/hourly/240hour.json?apiKey=6532d6454b8aa370768e63d6ba5a832e&units=e').json()
for i in r['forecasts']:
    print(i)
```

If unsure I will happily update to show you how to build dataframe and order.

Comment: Oh I didn't see the last sentence until now. If you would be willing to show the dataframe and order that would be much appreciated!! Thank you again.

Comment: I will have a look at it later.

Comment: haven't forgotten this